# ArcGIS 401 error during initialization of javascript map

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have a dumbed-down application to only reference a geometry service, and a feature service.

When the map is being initialized, it sends out a GET request of:
`http://my.server.com/ArcGISTEST/rest/info?f=json` but when using Chrome debug tools / fiddler I see it is returning HTTP 401 error

when I open this url in its own window/tab it produces the following output:

`{"currentVersion":10.02,"soapUrl":"a url is in here","secureSoapUrl":"a url is in here","authInfo":{"isTokenBasedSecurity":false}}`

It appears this is an object to determine the status/capability of the arcgis server to assist the javascript api.

Why am I getting this error?  How do I resolve it?  Could this be a symptom of my bigger problem (unable to edit features via javascript api).

Comment: Use the Fiddler "Compare" option to compare the request that got 401ed with the request that works.  It's likely there is some difference.

Comment: What kind of security have you set up on your server?

Comment: @mwalker
unsuccessful request has (differences here only):
    Accept: */*
    Origin: http://mapsd.nscorp.com
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    Referer: http://mapsd.nscorp.com/esriuc/noproxy.htm

successful:
    (none of the headers referenced above)
    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe We are using Windows (not Basic, but Negotiate/NTLM)

Answer (score 2):

This is a guess - but, if your viewer is not secured and your services are secured, then the browser might be re-using the HTTP connection (using HTTP keepalive) when the requests for your services are made.

To avoid this, apply the same security to your viewer as what would be used on the ArcGIS server.  Then, the browser will be forced to log in on the first page load and will continue to use the login credentials for subsequent requests.

Comment: I disabled anonymous authentication, and enabled Windows (NTLM) authentication on the website that the viewer is hosted on.  I am still getting the 401 though.

Comment: Check the IIS logs to determine who IIS thinks you are, especially for the 401 requests.  You can get a 401 for "I don't know who you are" as well as "I know who you are, and you're not allowed"

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the cross domain situation as the blow url shows:

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/cors/index.html